# Como hacer aparecer un mensaje propio de error de conexión en un webview de Android Studio?

Tags: android, webview-android

Soy nuevo en Android Studio y en Java. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que en un Webview en vez de que se muestre el mensaje de error de conexión por defecto se muestre un mensaje o imagen hecha por mi.

No pongo código porque todo es básico. El nombre de la actividad es el nombre por defecto y también el del layout.

Comment: Pues nada más añade la linea del mensaje (no pongo código porque es el básico para añadir mensajes de error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para gestionar los errores, retornos vacíos, etc, yo te recomiendo que uses componentes separados que muestres/ocultes dependiendo de la ocasión. En este caso en concreto es útil porque puedes incorporar un botón "reintentar" que vuelva a intentar cargar la página web de nuevo. Para tu caso en el que solo quieres mostrar un mensaje / imagen propia:

-En tu layout .xml crea un textview con tu mensaje personalizado (si es una imagen, usa el componente Imageview). Pon el componente con `visibility = "gone"` para que se encuentre oculto hasta que a ti te interese mostrarlo:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/lblError"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:text="Error de conexión"/>
```

-Ya en tu actividad, en caso de que se produzca el error de conexión, oculta el webview y muestra el textview que tenias oculto.

```
webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
lblError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Así tendrás el mensaje, imagen o componente que desees en caso de error. Cuando quieras mostrar el webview de nuevo solo tienes que hacer el paso contrario, mostrando el webview y ocultar de nuevo el textview de error.